# Criar lista de Actions com parâmetros e depois executa-la

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, actions

Gostaria de criar uma lista de Actions com parâmetros e depois fazer um foreach nessa lista e sair executando os métodos, cada um com seus respectivos parâmetros.

Algo mais ou menos com o código abaixo.

```
        private List<Action<int, int>> ListaAction = new List<Action<int, int>>();

    private int MetodoExecutar(int numero1, int numero2)
    {
        return numero1 + numero2;
    }

    private void MetodoMain()
    {
        int valor1 = 1;
        int valor2 = 2;

        ListaAction.Add(MetodoExecutar(valor1, valor2));
    }

    private void ExecutarListaDeActions()
    {
        foreach(Action acao in ListaAction)
        {
            acao();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes de responder, duas observações:

1. O delegate com retorno seria `Func` ao invés de `Action`;
2. Quando você delega um método, quem 'fornece' os valores dos parâmetros é a classe que detêm o poder de invocação do método `delegate`;

Condiserando que você entenda esses pontos (e tentando inferir algum sentido flutuando entre o título da pergunta, o código de exemplo apresentado e algo que seria utilizável), seria assim:

```
private List<Func<int, int, int>> ListaDelegate = new List<Func<int, int, int>>();

private int MetodoExecutar(int numero1, int numero2)
{
    return numero1 + numero2;
}

private int MetodoExecutar2(int numero1, int numero2)
{
    return numero1 * numero2;
}

private void MetodoMain()
{
    ListaDelegate.Add(MetodoExecutar);
    ListaDelegate.Add(MetodoExecutar2);
    ListaDelegate.Add((num1,num2) => { return num1 * (num1 + num2); }); // Delegate anônimo
}

private void ExecutarListaDeActions()
{
    int valor1 = 10;
    int valor2 = 20;

    foreach (Func<int, int, int> acao in ListaDelegate)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Resultado: " + acao(valor1, valor2).ToString());
}
```

A execução dos códigos envolvidos deve imprimir isso:

```
// Resultado: 30
// Resultado: 200
// Resultado: 300
```

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente a sua solução, mas a minha dúvida é o seguinte, quando eu incluo minha FUNC na lista, eu não consigo incluir ela passando os parâmetros no momento da inclusão na lista? Pois vamos supor, tenho uma rotina que calcula o numero me da o resultado do número e quero executar a função com o resultado desse número, nesse momento vou adicionar meu método com o número que resultou acima, teria como guardar essa function junto com os parâmetros que ela deve ser executada ? Essa seria minha grande dúvida e solução para meu problema.

Comment: Porque se isso não for possível compensa mais eu fazer uma Lista com o resultado dos meus parâmetros, depois realizar um foreach nela, e executar minha função principal passando os parametros necessário, dai não preciso usar nenhuma lista de FUNC<>. Correto ?

Comment: Bem, este seria um 4º assunto. O título foi o 1º, o código de exemplo que você escreveu na pergunta foi o 2º e o que eu sugeri como solução foi o 3º.

Comment: Mas sinalizei no código ´ListaAction.Add(MetodoExecutar(valor1, valor2));´ que gostaria de inserir a ACTION, ou FUNC já com seus parâmetros para execução, entendi perfeitamente o que sinalizou na sua respostas, só queria saber mesmo se existe a possibilidade de guardar essas FUNC na lista já com os seus parâmetros para execução.

Comment: Se o seu problema é como você descreveu agora, acredito que a solução não seja `delegates`. Seria como usar uma chave de fenda para cavar uma vala. Talvez a 'ferramenta' adequada seja recursividade, por exemplo. De qualquer forma, para mim não ficou muito claro seu problema, sugiro fazer uma outra pergunta contextualizando o problema com um [mcve]